# How to connect GitKraken to custom BitBucket server?

Tags: bitbucket, gitkraken

My problem is i have my own *bitbucket* server *bitbucket.mysite.com* and i can't figure out how to connect *gitkraken* to it. (My goal is to use the "Create Pull-Request" function.)

I tried under `Preferences-> Authentication->bitbucket.org->Connect to bitbucket` it redirects me to *bitbucket.org/account/signin/...*

So how to connect *gitkraken* to custom *bitbucket* server?

Comment: I just downloaded GitKraken to take a look at it and from what I can see it does not support connecting to a Bitbucket Server instance, nor even an arbitrary Git repository. Its Bitbucket integration redirects you to Bitbucket.org (a.k.a. Bitbucket Cloud), which is a separate thing altogether from a self-hosted Bitbucket Server.

You could give [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) a try - once you've added a repository and set up the Bitbucket Server url for it's remote configuration, you can right-click on a branch and use the "Create pull request" option from there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gitkraken now support BitBucket Server :
https://support.gitkraken.com/integrations/bitbucket-server/

Answer (score 1):

GitKraken has a "File" menu in the top-left corner.  Use it like so:

```
File --> Clone Repo --> [Bitbucket Clone URL]
```

e.g., Try dropping "http://test@vm.bit-booster.com/bitbucket/scm/bb/aui.git" into the URL. That's from a VM I run to let people try my [Bit-Booster Commit Graph and More](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.bit-booster.bb/server/overview) add-on, and so it's a legitimate Bitbucket Server clone url.

Comment: This is just for cloning a repo, the poster is asking about the integration with bitbucket itself, providing features like "Create pull request" which are not inherent to Git itself

Answer (score 0):

Had the same situation, and was able to get it working, although the method is a little half hearted.

I simply pulled the repo to my local machine using a different UI (in this case SourceForge), and then opened the repo from GitKraken. Then when I went to pull GitKracken prompted me for the username/password.

Considering this, it's possible that another responders answer of just doing a plain clone repo would work.